# Right way to handle DELETE request on RESTful API

Tags: rest, api, httprequest

I'm currently developing a REST service which has multiple request methods for each resource.

A requeriment is that the resources don't get permanently deleted at first instance, instead set an is_deleted flag to true to make possible the recovery of them later if necessary.

I'm currently doing setting the flag with a **DELETE** request, but i'm not sure if this a the right way to do it. I think i could do that with a **PATCH** when the flag is set to true.

I'm trying to follow a correct REST pattern to document it as well as possible. Which is the "right way to do it?

Comment: As REST is usually build on top of HTTP, [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) defines the semantics of `DELETE` and state that delete will remove the association (= link) to a resource but not necessarily the actual content of that resource. It may result in a further cleanup, but that is some implementation detail that is usually not of interest to clients.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a very common pattern to 'archive' information in an API/system rather than totally delete it.

What's important is not the specifics of the implementation, but that the intent of the given verb has been fulfilled.

So long as a `GET` request to the entity/document URL after the `DELETE` returns a `404` or similar, you're all good.

Comment: The important thing is that the _semantics_ are standard.  The implementation details are not constrained.

Comment: Agree with above, the fact that how a deleted resource is represented is specific to implementation. As long as your GET returns a 404 for a deleted resource you are good. Using PATCH is not a right option, because you will also allow updates of other fields along with delete flag with PATCH, which doesn't makes sense.